# How to make some parameters of `Func<>` optional?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

```
 var extraRules = new List<Func<string, string, string, bool>>
 {
        // Current letter is alphanumeric
        letter => Regex.IsMatch(letter, "[a-zA-Z]"),
 }
```

How do I make the second and third string optional?

I tried doing something like:

`private delegate bool Rules(string letter, string nextLetter = null, string nextNextLetter = null);`

and then:

```
var extraRules = new List<Rules>
 {
        // Current letter is alphanumeric
        letter => Regex.IsMatch(letter, "[a-zA-Z]"),
 }
```

But I get `Incompatible anonymous function signature`

How can I make some parameters of `Func<>` optional?

Comment: Can you describe what are you trying to achieve exactly? Seems like there's simple ways to do it.

Comment: I think this page could also give you a clue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't but you can use discards:

```
var extraRules = new List<Func<string, string, string, bool>>
{
    // Current letter is alphanumeric
    (letter, _, _) => Regex.IsMatch(letter, "[a-zA-Z]"),
};
```

Comment: I was also thinking to do it this way. Is this the only way to accomplish this in C#?

Comment: Note: you can use this kind of discard only with C# 9. With lower version you need to use `(letter, _, __) => ...`

Comment: @OS I would say it is the best one